# Is the Meanstack suitable for production?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have been looking at the various Meanstack frameworks out on the net - and whilst impressed with what they achieve I have one serious concern - the number of files used in a typical stack - meanstack.js uses over 15000 files whilst the bmean example has a modest 1900 in comparison.

The question I am asking myself is would I be happy to put my trust is such a system from a production view point - what happens when something goes wrong how easy is it going to be to find the answer? You can almost bet that when your most important customer logs on it is going to go haywire. Also what happens when Angular version 2 comes along it could require a complete rewrite but by then the stack your using has been customised and difficult to change?

Am I getting over concerned about the technology - my intended approach is to strip the client side code out of the bmean example and rewrite it with my own  - at least that way I know (and control) what goes on in the client. Do you think this is the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

With most systems there is a bit of preparation required before going to production. The same is true with mean.io (using multiple cpu's, improved aggregation, caching, etc etc)

The large number of files is essentially a product of the way npm handles dependencies. Each module is able to define independent versions of the same dependencies thus creating a bit of bloat but at the same time allowing a lot of flexability in nodejs code.

We currently have a number of mean.io projects in production phase and have been very happy with performance and the overall experience.

New releases of the project are scheduled every couple of months, upgrading should not be too much of a problem if you use the [package system](http://mean.io/#!/docs) correctly.

Issues with the project are handled and managed through [github issues](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues) additional support can be found on our irc (freenode #mean_io) channel as well as on [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/mean.io/).

For commercial support have a look at the [support page](http://mean.io/#!/support)